# WSO2 IS 5.2.0 change super administrator account

Tags: wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 IS 5.2.0

We have integrated it with AD/LDAP (using LDAPUserStoreManager). We had userA from AD as our super administrator. Using this user we have registered all our apps under “Service Providers”.

Now because of some organisation changes we have to connect to different LDAP server for user authentication. We have changed the LDAP configuration manually in the user-mgt.xml file to point to new AD/LDAP server and userB from new LDAP is our new super admin.

Problem: We are not able to see the list of APPs that we had registered under “Service Providers” when we login as “userB”.

Question how can we transfer the list of apps (ownership) to new administrator?

We tried to update SP_APP table from backend but it is still not solving the problem.
(e.g. update SP_APP  set username='userB' where APP_NAME='TestApp';)

Can someone please help us to know how can we transfer the list of apps under service provider so that it will be visible to new administrator?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Service Provider (SP), a role is created with it. If the name of the SP is "SomeName", a role is created is "Application/SomeName". Users with this particular role can see (and do any operation) that particular application.

So you need to assign these roles to the new admin user (or any other user that need to see the application) to make the applications visible to the new admin user.

See more information about creating service providers in WSO2 Identity Server in https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS541/Adding+and+Configuring+a+Service+Provider#AddingandConfiguringaServiceProvider-Addingaserviceprovider